# Disabling a Form's Transparency

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I'm working on a winforms application, one of my forms has `TransparencyKey` set to `White` so the `TextBoxes` are transparent as shown below:

[image]

I want to disable this transparency, I tried changing the `TransparencyKey` it works but ruins another color. How can I ***Disable*** transparency of the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set the Forms [`AllowTransparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.allowtransparency.aspx) Property to False.

Comment: Works like a knife. Simple and effective

Answer (score 4):

In the property sheet of the form, right-click `TransparencyKey` and choose `Reset`.

[image: VSTK]

Failing that, try setting `TransparencyKey` to an unused colour.

Comment: What if that color came up some day? I know it works and as I stated in my question I've had it done, BUT I feel it's not the right choice to make.

Comment: thanks but resetting the TransparencyKey just gives you the default color which is Transparent (and acts as White so when your form loads you can see through textboxes'), for DISABLING transparency we should set `AllowTransparency` as written above in Mark Hall's  answer. Thanks guys.